# "as" as a conjunction which means "while"

Tags: conjunctions

I would like to say "A gradually will become B while you keep doing C" using "as" like this:

> As I use it for a long time, it gradually becomes a treasure for me.

But I feel "as" requires a situation in which something gradually changes explained right after the word if a situation explained after comma also gradually changes. For example:

> As it got darker, the winds blew stronger.

Could you please tell me how I can express the first sentence properly?

Comment: "As I continue to use it..."?

Comment: @KateBunting A, I see!!  Thank you so much!

Comment: 'As' does not really require a situation that changes - as I walk along, I enjoy the sunshine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "as" is not at all limited to "a situation in which something gradually changes". It can also reer to a very sudden event

> - The great tree made a stunning sound as it struck the ground after it was chopped at the base.
> - The illumination shell turned night to day as it exploded.
> - Everyone present felt pity for Jane as she suffered a sudden seizure.
> - The crowd let out a gasp as the Senator announced his change of party.

"as" (in this sense) simply means "while" or "at the same time"/ It often, but not always, suggests some relation of cause between two things, but not always:

> - As Fred grew older, he became more politically conservative.
> - As Jane became more settled into her job, she developed a fondness for coffee.

> As I use it for a long time, it gradually becomes a treasure for me.

is as perfectly valid sentence. But so would

> After I had  used it only twice, it had already become a treasure for me.